# first empty row issue copy-pasting excel data in in a table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I've been reading and trying to learn a bit more of VBA, but I can't figure out yet. This script is copying, pasting the source data to another sheet, but not to the first empty row in the existing table on the sheet ("DATA") like it shoud, but to the first row in the table on the sheet overwriting existing data over there.

*-What am I missing?*

-And how can I put a check(argument?) in this script when a cell in the copied range is empty that should have a value, pasting is not executed and gives a warning to add missing data.

Much regards.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("Invoer Cursisten").Range("B11:K40").Copy

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("DATA").Activate
Cells(lastrow + 2, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

Worksheets("Invoer Cursisten").Range("B12:K41").Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: If you activate other sheet before querying last row, does something improve? (Not ot say that remarks like "I found this code" and "time is running short" create bad smell.)

Comment: Will try later. Thnks! As well for commenting the remarks.

Comment: Is this code in the workbook containing these two worksheets? If so, use `ThisWorkbook` to qualify the worksheets i.e. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(...)`. You are clearing `B12:K41`, which would suggest that you have headers in row `11` yet you are copying the headers with `B11:K41` to a worksheet where you need to find the last row. You haven't qualified the range `Range(...)` with the correct worksheet i.e. you need to use `Worksheets("DATA").Range(...)`. `SkipBlanks:=True` may not produce the result you expect. Please explain which cells could be blank (or just empty) for the warning to appear.

Comment: The copy-paste part works as it should now. Changed everything as suggested by Arvo and @VBasic2008. The part of checking I'd like to be performed before pasting will get attention later. It's no prio right now.